# Microsoft.Ajax.Utilities.Minifier for css file lose @keyframes rule

Tags: css, css-animations, microsoft-ajax-minifier

I used Microsoft.Ajax.Utilities.Minifier for css file. The results is a file without @keyframes rule that I used for css animation.

I saw the cssParser and cssSettings parameters but I havent't find nothing to include @keyframes rule into minifier.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Could really do with finding out if you solved this??

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have a solution yet